# How to smooth out a raster in r while maintaining the data limits?

Tags: r, raster, smoothing

I have a raster that looks a little 'pixel-y' and I want to create a more smoothed out version to produce a nice map.
Here's an example dataset:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
```

I tried:

```
plot(r,interpolate=TRUE)
```

but I don't like how it looks. Then I tried:

```
rr <- disaggregate(r, 3, method='bilinear')
```

which looks alot better, but it changes the upper limit of my values. I need the new values created from the smoothing to maintain the limits of the old data (i.e. 0 to 1)
Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Not sure what package you are using. These functions are not part of base R as far as I can tell. You can control the limits of `plot` with `ylim` and `xlim`.

Comment: I have edited my question. It is the raster package. I don't want to simply alter the limits in the plot...I want the smoothed surface data not to exceed the maximum value in the original dataset. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to clamp the values after resampling

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10, xmn=0, xmx=10, ymn=0, ymx=10, vals=(1:100)/100)
rr <- disaggregate(r, 3, method='bilinear')
rr <- clamp(rr, 0, 1)
```

Which is probably good enough as you should only get (a few) values outside the observed range at the edges.

An alternative approach would be to use focal.

```
x <- disaggregate(r, 3)
f <- focal(x, matrix(1,3,3))
```

Comment: Many thanks. `clamp` worked. Re: the `focal` option...this isn't constrained to any limits that I can see? Am I missing something?

Comment: It is not constrained, but it cannot go outside of the observed range if you do not use "bilinear" with disaggregate